# Should I close my questions that have 'obvious' answers?

Tags: discussion

I'm a relatively new programmer and sometimes I simply don't know which terminology I need to use when doing my own research to find out a coding practice. As a result I sometimes post questions that are 'obvious' to most experienced users. These questions typically get downvoted (which I understand but don't appreciate) but at least most people are patient and answer my questions thoroughly and help me to learn.

My question is whether or not I should flag the question for closure because it is 'obvious'. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514731/using-a-string-in-place-of-an-object-when-accessing-it) is an example of such a question (I just posted it this evening). I want to help provide more content to the site but I also want to avoid cluttering it.

Can anyone weigh in on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obvious questions are also constructive. But I think SO has enough obvious questions so make sure that your question is not a duplicate.

And one question is obvious for person a and that same time it could be tough for person b so closing question because we think it is obvious for experts is not a good idea  at all(imho).